# Streaming MPMoviePlayer: overlay button showing up too early

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am trying to overlay a button on the MPMoviePlayer on my app. I can't get it to work properly on a streaming movie. The overlay shows up on top of the view that launched the movie object (in my case a table view). I'm pretty much following the MPMoviePlayer example exactly.   I would also be interested in making the overlay show up if the movieplayer window is touched.  I am not experienced with iphone development at all.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ samuelreh

did you find out the solution for this?
i have the same problem as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is taken almost directly from the MoviePlayer sample project, where overlayView is the view you've defined.

```
NSArray *windows = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];  
if ([windows count] > 1) {
    // Locate the movie player window
    UIWindow *moviePlayerWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    [moviePlayerWindow addSubview:self.overlayView];  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The MPMoviePlayer is probably added as a subview of the UIWindow instance in your app delegate (similar to the UIKeyboard).

You don't actually have any control over the MoviePlayer view, however. I could be wrong, but I don't think adding overlays on the MPMoviePlayer view is supported. You can try adding your "overlay" to the UIWindow instance and see what happens.